# How to remove first word "the" from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get list of string's using an API. For example:

```
'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring 2001'
'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers 2002'
'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King 2003'
```

I want to convert it like this:

```
'Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring 2001'
'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers 2002'
'Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King 2003'
```

Somehow I did it by using the below script but with some bugs. See test1 and test2.

```
function myFunction(str) { 
    var position = str.search(/the/i);
    if (position == 0) { 
         var str = str.substring( str.indexOf(" ") + 1, str.length );
    }
    return str;
}
```

test1:

```
str = "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring 2001"
```

result:

```
return = "Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring 2001" // that's what i want
```

test2:

```
str = "There Will Be Blood 2007"
```

result:

```
returns = 'Will Be Blood' // that's what i don't want
```

I just want to remove first word "The" from string.

Comment: Use:  `str.replace(/The /g,'');`

Comment: why not compare `/the\s/` instead. this will compare the word the with a space after it.

Comment: simply adding space wont work as the space could be any white space character here

Comment: Use a regular expression: `/^The\s/i` The `^` is important as it will ensure you *only* remove leading instances of `The`

Comment: can check this [link](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm) for other reg exp symbols

Comment: \b in a pattern matches a word boundary. For example, 'The\b' will not match 'There'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression to achieve this. Specifically `/^The\s/i`. Note that the `^` is important as it ensures that the match only finds leading instances of  `The`.

```js
var arr = ['The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring 2001', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers 2002', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King 2003'];

var re = /^The\s/i;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(re, '');
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an space:

```js
function myFunction(str) { 
  var position = str.search(/the\s/i);
  if(position == 0){ 
    var str = str.substring( str.indexOf(" ") + 1, str.length );
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(myFunction("The Ring of Lords: The ring of Lords"));
console.log(myFunction("There Ring of Lords: The ring of Lords"));
```

Comment: /the / wont work for the text that may contain white space which is not space

Comment: suggestion use `/the\s+/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the substr function :

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i){
    if(list[i].substr(0, 4).toLowerCase() == "the ")
        list[i] = list[i].substr(4, list[i].length);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pk4fjwyf/

Answer (score -1):

Simply Use this

```
var string = "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring 2001";
var result = string.replace(/^The\s/i, " ");
alert(result);
```